# Script is not running on server, it can't find my gems

Tags: ruby

I have a simple script of 2 files I just uploaded to my server.

1. Gemfile
2. hello.rb

When I run:

```
bundle install
```

It installed the gems.

When I run:

ruby hello.rb

I get the error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- HTTPClient (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

I ran gem install for each of the gems again, still same error.

`gem list` command lists the gems correctly also.

**What could the issue be?**

I have already run this also:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

**Update**
gem env output is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Ruby 1.9.1 is really old.  Are you really trying to use it?  What is the output of `which gem` and can you figure out what version of Ruby `gem` is using?

Comment: @DavidGrayson which gem says /usr/bin/gem

Comment: OK, so what gems are listed in your Gemfile and specifically which gem to you think provides a file named `HTTPClient.rb`?  Usually Ruby file names are lowercase.

Comment: What is the output of ``ruby -v``?

Comment: How did you install ``ruby``? ``rbenv``, ``rvm``, default install?

Comment: It is possible, your system ruby is different from the one being run by bundle. What is the result of trying @Horacio answer?

Comment: @zhon ruby version is ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux].

Comment: @zhon it was default install.  Now I installed ruby 2.3.1 and same issue.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require :default
```

and then run with

```
bundler exec ruby hello.rb
```

If you want to know where are your gems, try

```
gem env
```

Comment: This is generally correct but using `bundler exec` is reserved for situations where running it straight-up doesn't work, or the tool you're using, like `rake`, is different in the `Gemfile` than in your base environment.

Answer (score 1):

I updated to ruby 2.3.1 and I also renamed the following:

require 'HTTPClient'

to

require 'httpclient'

I'm not sure why but locally my script worked fine, but on the server it didnt' accept 'HTTPClient' (upper case vs lower case).

It works now.

Comment: Are you developing on an OS with case insensitive file system like OS X? And deploying on Linux with case sensitive. That could do it.

Comment: @Doon yes osx locally, ubuntu as the server.

Comment: Well that explains it.  OS X is case preserving but not case sensitive by default. Ubuntu is case sensitive so case matters or else it cannot find the library.